# Android NetworkInfo.getTypeName() return values

Tags: android, network-programming, connectivity

**Intro:** Using the getTypeName() method returns the human readable String value of a network information examined. Trying to locate the possible returned values led me to ConnectivityManager's getNetworkTypeName method.

Some of the values returned can be: "MOBILE_DUN", "WIMAX", "BLUETOOTH", "ETHERNET", etc...

**Question:** What are the values i should consider when asking if the device is connected?

**Question:** If, for instance, i'm connected with "MOBILE_DUN" or "ETHERNET", am i still considered connected with "MOBILE"/"WIFI"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code;

```
 ConnectivityManager  cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if(cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            .isConnectedOrConnecting()
            || cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    .isConnectedOrConnecting())

 {
 // do functionality


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Question**: What are the values i should consider when asking if the device is connected?

**Answer**: The values can be found in ConnectivityManager.getNetworkTypeName(int type) method.

**Question**: If, for instance, i'm connected with "MOBILE_DUN" or "ETHERNET", am i still considered connected with "MOBILE"/"WIFI"?

**Answer**: The answer is yes. It seems your device can be connected to a number of these networks simultaneously.